# Test that an object calls a private method in Ruby with Minitest

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

Given the following ruby code, I want to ensure that the private method, `start`, only gets started if the app has been configured to run it. I think that means I need to mock the class and stub the private method, but I'm just not putting it together right. Anyone able to give me a push?

```
module Work
  class Thing
    def initialize(value:)
      @local_state = value
      if Rails.configuration.report_loop
        start
      end
    end

    def change(new_value)
      @local_state = new_value
    end

    private

    def start
      Thread.new {perform_reporting}.tap do |thread|
        thread.abort_on_exception = true if thread
      end
    end

    def perform_reporting
      loop do
        sleep 5
        log @local_state
      end
    end
end
```

Here is what I'm trying that isn't working

```
def test_it_starts_reporting_automatically
  mock = Minitest::Mock.new
  mock.expect :start, true
  Work::Thing.stub :start, mock do
      hb = Work::Thing.new value: "test"
  end
  assert_mock mock
end
```

Comment: Mock `Thread#new`, not `Thing#start`.

Comment: Generally if a method is private, the tests shouldn't have any idea that the method exists. Perhaps you should make it public if it's going to be visible from the outside anyway. --- _Reason: you don't want to depend on private behaviour, because it's an implementation detail that's likely to change. This will leave you with fragile tests._

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to mock Thread#new. `Thread.stub(:new, nil) {Thread.new {puts "shouldn't print"}}` will still print the string that shouldn't print. @mudasobwa

Comment: `Thread#new` is a class method. I am not familiar with `minitest`, but I’d suggest `Thread.singleton_class.stub(:new, nil)` should work.